# Deinterlace Mythbuntu 0.24.1

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

Mythbuntu 0.24.1

I don't have a Deinterlacing option like shown here: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Deinterlacing

Is it moved? My picture is top & bottom. When paused, it looks correct.

Going through the CPU+, CPU++, etc, I can see the options (and have tried many options), but no go. Hauppauge HD PVR, cable box, newish CPU, onboard video.

Thanks for the help!